# apply function to selected text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

http://webwrinkle.com/

I have a basic form up on the above listed web address. I would want the option for the user to be able to apply a javascript or jquery function to selected text in the form. Is a php file, so the info would go into a database, and then output as html in a page.

I was thinking that the user could select text entered into the form, apply the function via a button, and the function tied to the button would input link tags on both ends of the selected text to make the selected text a clickable weblink on a posted php page. (the same kind of functionality in TinyMCE) Let me know if more info is needed, or I didn't explain it fully. I should be able to figure out how to build the PHP functions that need applied if I can get started in the right direction...

thanks for all your help!

Comment: what actually you want to do ?

Comment: If I were to enter a weblink (without tags) into the textarea, and then click a button, the button would add a tags on each side of the address that I had entered into the textarea, making it an actual clickable link on the target page.

Comment: I imagine it would be javascript or jquery since it would need to add the a tags before it was entered into the database. (pre server side)

Comment: why dont you save data into database as it is (without anchor tags) ? and at the time of data retrival from database, simply turn the text into anchor tag links...

Comment: I would not be touching the data once entered by the user. I would have the info pulled out and posted as a page on a schedule, like a weekly bulletin. Could I set this functionality up without having to touch this? ie. set up a function that looks for any http://... and then prepend and append a tags on each side when output?

Comment: I was thinking of the same type of thinking for unordered and ordered lists as well, and not sure how I would search for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, you shouldn't have to send anything to the server until you're ready to submit the "memo" -- you can do all of the editing you described entirely with javascript.

First of all, you need to be able to retrieve the currently selected text.  You can use something like this:

```
var memoBox = document.getElementById("memo"); //get the memo input element

var startIndex = memoBox.selectionStart, endIndex = memoBox.selectionEnd; //store the start and end of the user's selection
var selectedText = memoBox.value.substring(startIndex,endIndex); //retrieve and store the selected text
```

Now, let's say you want to add a link to the selected text.  You could write a function like this:

```
function addLinkToSelected() {
    var memoBox = document.getElementById("memo");
    var startIndex = memoBox.selectionStart, endIndex = memoBox.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = memoBox.value.substring(startIndex,endIndex);

    var linkURL = prompt("Link target: "); //ask the user for a link target
    var linkTag = '<a href="'+linkURL+'">'; //construct a link tag

    memoBox.value = memoBox.value.substring(0,startIndex) + linkTag 
                   + selectedText + "</a>" + memoBox.value.substring(endIndex+1);
}
```

Now, just add a button and call the function when it is clicked:

```
<input type="button" value="add link" onclick="addLinkToSelected()" />
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, so feel free to add more detail.  I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nDYt/) where you can check out a working example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`link()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp) function of javascript to convert text into a hyper text link

ex.

```
function addLink() {
    var memoBox = document.getElementById("memo");
    alert(memoBox.link(memoBox));
}
```

Comment: please explain. I enter text into a form field, then select a section of it, click the button, and the tags are entered on each side?

Comment: for instance, I type in www.webwrinkle.com, click the button, and tags are entered on both sides?

Comment: yes you typed www.webwrinkle.com, and after clicking the button, the tags are entered on both sides, for example see the edited answer ...