# How to append text on select text inside of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have try to use jquery create a simple rich text,

```
$('#textarea').bind('keyup', function(e) {
  var data = $('#textarea').val()
  $('#data').html(data.replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
});

$('#bold').click();
```

anyone know how to append text on **select text** inside of **textarea**(append front and back)
ex. append `<b>`select text`</b>` and don't show any tag inside of textarea `<b>`

http://jsfiddle.net/KnyTt/

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: I don't think you can add style to a text inside a textearea, you should use what @elclanrs link you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058334/apply-function-to-selected-text/17058648#17058648) on how to format selected text.  Unfortunately, an HTML textarea component simply won't display HTML formatted text.  You could certainly check out some HTML/JS rich text editor components such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) instead of trying to write your own.

**EDIT**: You could apply my above answer to an editable div (or some other element that displays formatting) using @elclanrs [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable).